# Hosting another static website to firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a static website at firebase with a domain connected, how I can to deploy another small website to same domain to url look something like? : example.com/weather

create aother app insite same project on firebase

It's require to integrate this weather app inside main website or it's impossible to achive like this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to deploy content to a specific path in Firebase Hosting and manage it separately.  All of the content for the entire site must be deployed together as a single unit.

Comment: Thank you for the awnser, then I should think to another aprouch for ending this project.